# Accessing objects when changing from NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

In one of my classes I have changed from an `NSMutableArray` to a `NSMutableDictionary`.
Before I accessed objects from other class like this:

```
tmpDeadline = [_taskDays[i] deadline]; //deadline is a object of another class
```

And accessed methods like this:

```
[_taskDays[datePlace]addDatedTask:d]; //addDatedTask is a method in another class
```

But now I can't do this anymore since I get a lot of errors which I don't really know how to handle.
What I do know is that I want use the other class's "deadline" as key and the instance of the class as object.

Here is the code (I have given the code that gives me problem the comment *ERROR*:

```
#import "LIUTaskCalendar.h"
#import "LIUTaskDay.h"
#import "LIUDatedTask.h"

@interface LIUTaskCalendar ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *_taskDays;
}

@end

@implementation LIUTaskCalendar
- (void)addDatedTasks:(LIUDatedTask *)d {
    if (!_taskDays) {
        _taskDays = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    }

    NSInteger length = [_taskDays count];
    NSDate *tmpDeadline;
    NSDate *tmpDueDate;
    NSInteger dateExist = 0;
    NSInteger datePlace = 0;
    NSDate *tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        tmpDueDate = d.dueDate;
        tmpDeadline = [_taskDays[i] deadline]; //*ERROR*



        if ([tmpDueDate compare:tmpDeadline] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            continue;
        } else if ([tmpDueDate compare:tmpDeadline] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            continue;
        }   else {
            dateExist = 1;
            datePlace = i;
            break;
        }


    }

    if (dateExist == 1) {
        [_taskDays[datePlace]addDatedTask:d]; //*ERROR*
    } else {
        LIUTaskDay *tmpLIUTaskDay = [[LIUTaskDay alloc]init];
        [tmpLIUTaskDay addDatedTask:d];
        tmpLIUTaskDay.deadline = d.dueDate;
        //[_taskDays setObject:d forKey:tmpLIUTaskDay.deadline];
        [_taskDays addObject:tmpLIUTaskDay]; //*ERROR*
    }


}

- (void)removeTaskDay:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDate *tmpDeadline;
    NSDate *tmpDeleteDate;
    NSInteger dateExist = 0;
    NSDate *dateDelete;

    NSInteger length = [_taskDays count];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        tmpDeleteDate = date;
        tmpDeadline = [_taskDays[i] deadline]; //*ERROR*

        if ([tmpDeleteDate compare:tmpDeadline] == NSOrderedAscending) {
            continue;
        } else if ([tmpDeleteDate compare:tmpDeadline] == NSOrderedDescending) {
            continue;
        }   else {
            dateExist = 1;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (dateExist == 1) {
        //[_taskDays removeObjectForKey:dateDelete];
        [_taskDays removeObjectAtIndex:dateDelete]; //*ERROR*
    } else {
        return;
    }

}

@end
```

If you need me to provide the code for the other class to then don't
   hesitate to tell me.

Thanks in advance

*UPDATE*
Changed from this:

```
[_taskDays addObject:tmpLIUTaskDay];
```

To this:

```
[_taskDays setObject:d forKey:tmpLIUTaskDay.deadline];
```

Comment: Why did you change it from array to dictionary?

Comment: Because it will be easier to access the tasks from the calendar using the dates :)

Comment: So the keys to the dictionary is the day of the month?  I don't think that will make it easier.  Also have you considered multiple tasks on the same day?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using [_taskDays[datePlace]addDatedTask:d]; which I also get an error for cause I don't know how to changed it.

Answer (score 0):

`taskDays` is dictionary, while you are using it as if it is an array `_taskDays[i]` in

```
tmpDeadline = [_taskDays[i] deadline]; //*ERROR*
```

also here:

```
[_taskDays addObject:tmpLIUTaskDay]; //*ERROR*
```

To fetch from dictionary or add a new key-value pair you should do like this:

```
 tmpDeadline = [_taskDays[@"taskDay"] deadline];
```

and

```
[_taskDays addObject:addObject:tmpLIUTaskDay forKey:@"taskDay"];
```

Comment: Will try those things, but how do I make it work in this:

    [_taskDays[datePlace]addDatedTask:d];
  
Here I need to access a method from another class

Comment: I read your other comments, you cannot have same keys twice. You will loose the first value. You must be aware of KVP/Dictionary. And your other question...`how to access a method from another class`. Create an instance of the class and use it. If you want same set of values then you need to have a singleton class.

Comment: Keys are for every day of the months (NSDate), and in every day there can be multiple tasks.
Can you show me an example of how to access a method from another class with dictionary?